# How can I switch a user from a room to other room?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Considering that i have a friend,and he has a session and his own room, when i'm going to send it a message, i want to he switch room to other room where i'm too.

This the function when i create the own room with static sessions.

```
socket.on('chat-in', function(data){
    session.id_usuario = session.idUsuario;
    session.save();
    socket.username = session.id_usuario;
    usernames[session.id_usuario] = session.id_usuario; 



    socket.leave(socket.room);

      socket.join(usernames[session.id_usuario]);

  serv.sockets.emit('mensaje',usernames);


  });
```

And this code is that i want to switch the rooms

```
socket.on('createRoom',function(datos){

     var obj = {};
      obj.mensaje = datos.mensaje;
      obj.from = datos.idMe;
      obj.to = datos.idFriend;

    var room = datos.id;
    var mensaje = datos.mensaje;
    var idMe = datos.idMe;
    var idFriend = datos.idFriend;
    var roomTrue = 'luisybeto';


    var oldRoom  = socket.room;
    socket.leave(socket.room);
    socket.join(roomTrue);
    socket.room = newroom;

      serv.sockets.in(roomTrue).emit('tester',obj);

    });
```

HTML

```
 $('#sendMessage').click(function(){
              var datos = {};
              datos.idFriend = idAmigoPost;
              datos.idMe = $('.id').attr('id');
              console.log(datos.idMe);
              datos.mensaje = $('#mensajeInboxSend').val();
              io.emit('createRoom',datos);

             });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to emit subscribe and unsubscribe events from the client,

**When user comes to room 1**

Client:

```
socket.emit('subscribe', 'room1');
```

**When user switches to room 2**

Client:

```
socket.emit('unsubscribe', 'room1');   
socket.emit('subscribe', 'room2');
```

Server:

```
socket.on('subscribe', function(room) { 
    socket.join(room); 
});
socket.on('unsubscribe', function(room) {  
    socket.leave(room); 
});
```

Reference:  https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms